# How to properly sort a backbone js collection after fetch()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm at wits end trying to figure out how to sort backbone collections on page load. The documentation seems to be a little thin in this area, as defining a comparator is definitely not enough. All the examples I can find seem to focus on definition of comparators, which shouldn't be my problem.

Here is a basic example illustrating my problem:

```
$(function() {

var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        amount: 0
    },

    sync: function(method, collection, options) {
        options.url = this.methodToURL(method.toLowerCase());
        Backbone.sync(method, collection, options);
    },

    methodToURL: function(method) {
        switch(method) {
            case 'create':
                return "item";
                break;
            case 'read':
                return "item/" + this.get('id');
                break;
            case 'update':
                return "item";
                break;
            case 'delete':
                return "item/" + this.get('id');
                break;
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

});

var ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item,

    url: 'items',

    comparator: function(item) {
        return item.get("amount");
    }
});

var items = new ItemList;

var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: _.template($("#item-template").html()),

            render: function() {
                   this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                   return this;
            }
    });

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#item-view"),

    initialize: function() {
        this.amount = $("#item-amount");
        this.listenTo(items, 'add', this.addItem);
        items.fetch();
    },

    addItem: function(item) {
        var view = new ItemView({model: item});
        $("#item-list").append(view.render().el);
    }

});

var app = new AppView();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be better to listen to the `"sync"` event on the collection rather than the `"add"` event.

The "`add"` event will probably get called as individual items are added to the collection and they may not be added in the order that they will eventually be sorted.

So try changing the `listenTo` line to:

```
this.listenTo(items, 'sync', this.addItems);
```

Then your addItems function could be re-written as:

```
addItems: function(items) {
    $("#item-list").empty();
    items.each(function(item) {
        var view = new ItemView({model: item});
        $("#item-list").append(view.render().el);
    });
}
```